# Hash and salt MySQL field type

Tags: mysql

So I'm new to the security scene, and I'm storing the user's hash and salt in a MySQL table. But I don't know what field type to use for hash and salt. Is it text?

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on which hash function and what type of salt you are using, but a CHAR or VARCHAR would work.

The hash should be an alphanumeric string of fixed length. One of the advantages of hashing is that a user could have a 2000-character long Unicode string for a password, and the hash could still be 32 bytes of ASCII.

The salt depends on your choice, but will probably also be an ASCII string of fixed length.

You can probably use CHAR instead of VARCHAR since these will be fixed length. Depending on a number of other factors, this could help performance. Although it's probably not worth thinking too hard about, and a VARCHAR would be fine.